# Can I release a bug fix to a previous version of an iOS app through iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Here's the situation: I have just released a minor version (3.5.3) of my app that still supports iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2), but I will soon be releasing a major version (4.0) that requires iOS 4.3 and up, so iPhone 3G will no longer be supported from 4.0 onwards.

I'd like to know if I can continue to support the 3.5.x version in the future by releasing updates to that e.g. 3.5.4 - will iTunes Connect understand that this is an incremental release to 3.5.3 and thus not offer it to those on 4.0? Does it understand that 4.0 will always be > 3.x? Or can there only ever be one version active at a time? Seems that way...

If the latter is true then I guess the way round it would be to submit 2 new versions - 3.5.4 and 4.0.1 - and release the 4.0.1 immediately after 3.5.4.

Has anyone had experience of doing this?
I'd obviously like to avoid this scenario if possible, but I don't want to have to leave my 3G customers in the lurch if something serious comes up.

Comment: I'm no authority on this but I suspect your workaround isn't valid either.  If there's a 4.0 in the store, then 3.5.4 is unlikely to be accepted.

Comment: The way I understand it, to support two versions of one app in the store the 4.0 release would need to be submitted as a new app, with a new bundle ID and maybe even a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you submit the new 4.3 version as a different app entirely (ie. not an upgrade to the original app).

If you submit the 4,3 app as an update, then the old app will be overwritten and no legacy support can be provided for it.

Users that haven't updated to 4.3 or are using older hardware simply won't be notified that your app has been updated until they update their OS or hardware.

I also think that if you do try to submit two separate versions of the same app, with the only difference between small feature changes and an OS requirement, then one of them will be rejected.